# Edit application "About" menu MacOSX (with tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When you look at the menu bar of an application, there is a menu in bold with the name of the application and inside that menu there is an about option. How do you go about editing this about menu with tkinter in python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite some research, I found the answer:

```py
from tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk=Tk()

    def show_about_menu(self): #function for about window
        Label(Toplevel(self.tk),text='An about menu.').pack()

    def show_help(self): #function for help window
        Message(Toplevel(self.tk),text='There are a series of generalised events in tkinter. Some of which are OS specific, such as any starting with "tk::mac::". Others are more general such as "tkAboutDialog", which is used when the menu option "<app>/About <app>" is called.').pack()

    def show_preferences(self): #function for preferences window
        Label(Toplevel(self.tk),text='Some preferences.').pack()

    def start(self):
        self.tk.createcommand('tkAboutDialog',self.show_about_menu) #set about menu
        self.tk.createcommand('tk::mac::ShowPreferences',self.show_preferences) #set preferences menu
        self.tk.createcommand('tk::mac::ShowHelp',self.show_help) #set help menu
        self.tk.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    App().start()
```